# How to render only paypal button and hide debit card button, using @paypal/react-paypal-js, in react project

Tags: css, reactjs, paypal

I am now developing some shopping project using React.
And I have some issue on paypal payment gateway.
Here is how my payment gateway looks like.
[Paypal Payment gate way.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5g0We.png)
It renders two buttons (paypal, and debit card)
But I only want to render the paypal button.
Here is my code snippets for this.

```
import {
  PayPalButtons,
  usePayPalScriptReducer,
} from "@paypal/react-paypal-js";

<Box>
  <PayPalButtons
    style={{ layout: "vertical" }}
    className="paypal-buttons"
    createOrder={(data, actions) => onCreateOrder(data, actions)}
    onApprove={(data, actions) => onApproveOrder(data, actions)}
  />
</Box>
```

Could you help me?
Thanks.

I tried to change the css as diplay: none
but that is rendered inside iFrame.
So I can't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucky Shark.
I saw your issue.
That can be solved by using

> fundingSource

props in PayPalButtons.

So you can import FUNDING objects from @paypal/react-paypal-js.

> import { FUNDING } from "@paypal/react-paypal-js";

and update your code like this.

```
<PayPalButtons
  style={{ layout: "vertical" }}
  className="paypal-buttons"
  createOrder={(data, actions) => onCreateOrder(data, actions)}
  onApprove={(data, actions) => onApproveOrder(data, actions)}
  fundingSource={FUNDING.PAYPAL}
/>
```

I hope this will help you.
Best.

Comment: Yes, this is working.
Thanks Eagering Dev.

Comment: Anytime. I am glad to help you.

Comment: I have one more question.

Comment: What if I want to render several paypal buttons, (using fundingSource props)
I see it is string type, not array type.

Comment: Then you can render them several time using different fundingSource props.

like 
fundingSources.map(fs => <PayPalButtons
  style={{ layout: "vertical" }}
  className="paypal-buttons"
  createOrder={(data, actions) => onCreateOrder(data, actions)}
  onApprove={(data, actions) => onApproveOrder(data, actions)}
  fundingSource={fs}
/>

Comment: Yes, that can be solution.
Thanks, again.